# php login consulta

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Buenas, me estoy introduciendo en el mundo de `php` con `mysql`. La cuestión es que estoy tratando de validar un **login** mediante un `GET` con datos que escribo en la **url**. No me estaría saliendo y no se porqué.

Este es mi archivo **login.php**

```
    <?php
  require ('conexion.php');
  
  $user = $_GET['usuario'];
  $pass = $_GET['password'];
  
  $conn = Conectar();
  $query = "SELECT idUsuario, usuario, password, idSuscripcionFk FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$user' AND password = '$pass' LIMIT 1;";
  
  $resultado = $conn->prepare($query);
      $resultado->execute(); 
      echo "$resultado";
      
  if(count($resultado)>0){
      echo 'Ingreso exitoso.';
  }else{
      echo 'Datos incorrectos.';
  }
```

Y a mi url le digo:

```
dom.com/login.php?usuario=usuario&password=password
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Siguiendo la respuesta de **David JP:**

```
<?php
  require ('conexion.php');
  
  $user = $_GET['usuario'];
  $pass = $_GET['password'];
  
  $conn = Conectar();
  echo "$conn";
  
  
  $query = "
    SELECT idUsuario 
      FROM usuarios 
      WHERE usuario = ? AND password = ?
      LIMIT 1;
    ";
  
  $resultado = $conn->prepare($query);
  $resultado->bind_param('ss',$user,$pass);
  $resultado->execute();
  $resultado->bind_result($idUsuario);
  if($resultado->fetch())
    echo 'Ingreso exitoso';
  else echo 'Datos incorrectos';
```

Y con la url `dom.com/login.php?usuario=usuario&password=password`

A su vez, con la respuesta de **NikolaTesla**, el código php quedó así:

```
<?php
  require ('conexion.php');
  
  $user = $_GET['usuario'];
  $pass = $_GET['password'];
  
  $conn = Conectar();
  echo "$conn";
  
  
  $query = "SELECT idUsuario, usuario, password, idSuscripcionFk FROM usuarios 
  WHERE usuario = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1";
  
  $resultado = $conn->prepare($query);
  $resultado->bind_param('ss',$user,$pass);
  $resultado->execute(); 
  $registro = $resultado->get_result();
  if($registro->num_rows > 0){
      echo 'Ingreso exitoso.';
  }else{
      echo 'Datos incorrectos.';
  }
```

Y con la misma url `dom.com/login.php?usuario=usuario&password=password`

El resultado es el mismo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No imprime nada.

Adjunto mi `config.php`:

```
<?php

    define('DB_HOST', 'ip');
    define('DB_NAME', 'db');
    define('DB_USER', 'user');
    define('DB_PASS', 'pass);
    define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

Y mi **conexion.php**

```
<?php
  require 'config.php';

  function Conectar(){
    $conn = null;
    try {
      $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
      $conn->exec('set names ' . DB_CHARSET);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      //echo 'Conexion exitosa...';
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
      die();
    }
    return $conn;
  }
```

En mi `BD` en `MySQL` no hay ningún usuario con esos valores, por lo que me gustaría mostrar el `echo` con los valores que dice que los datos son incorrectos, pero no me funciona. ¿Alguien me podría guiar un poco?

Comment: Que te muestra si haces un echo var_dump($resultado) ??

Comment: Nunca pases datos de login usando método GET, quedan visibles en la ruta. Se debe usar POST.

Comment: Hola. ¿ Usas PDO para la conexión ? estoy preparando una respuesta y acabo de caer en cuenta de que no tengo ese dato.

Comment: @quevedo Por el método `prepare()` tiene pinta de ser `mysqli`

Comment: Estoy usando PDO para esto

Comment: Antes de llegar aquí, probé `echo var_dump($resultado)` y no imprimía nada @NikolaTesla

Comment: LO sé, pero como esto son pruebas que realizo para mi mismo estoy usando el get para pasar los parámetros por url @quevedo

Comment: Otro *problema* que veo en tu código y en las respuestas es el hecho de un Select de columnas y posterior evaluar como un valor numérico, en estos casos lo que le falta a tu `SELECT` ES UN `COUNT(*)`PARA saber el número de filas que obtuvo

Comment: @DavidJP el método prepare existe tanto para [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) como así [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Franco, te hago los siguientes comentarios:

- Tienes una mezcla de herramientas muy interesante pues por un lado te conectas con PDO pero por otro usas métodos como **`bind_param()`** que son de mysqli y eso no es correcto (*elige*)

  - Bajo este punto entonces métodos como los siguientes no son aplicables y no deberías estarlos usando bajo el esquema de PDO:

    - **`bind_result`**
    - **`num_rows`**
    - **`bind_param`**
- Tu consulta debería hacer un conteo en razón de las filas que devuelva *o no* producto de los valores que le pases y no elegir columnas puesto que según eo tu única intención de fondo es verificar si el usuario existe o no y en razón de eso notificar
- Como estás usando PDO, entonces el valor se verifica por medio del método **`fetchColumn()`**

Considera esto como punto de partida:

```
$consultaUsuarios = Conectar()->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                         FROM usuarios 
                                         WHERE usuario = :usuario 
                                         AND password = :password
                                         LIMIT 1");
$consultaUsuarios->bindParam(":usuario", $variable1);
$consultaUsuarios->bindParam(":password", $variable2);
$consultaUsuarios->execute();
```

Ahora mediante un sencillo `if` evaluamos si la consulta retornó o no filas así:

```
 if ($consultaUsuarios->fetchColumn() > 0)  {
     /*
       acciones si existe el usuario
     */
 } else {
     /*
         acciones si no existe
     */
 }
```

Comentarios extra:

- PDO acepta tanto marcadores de nombre como de posición, yo usé los primeros
- No pases como ya te indican los datos del login por get, usa POST
- Este código necesitaría trabajo extra para verificar puntos por ejemplo la ejecución de la consulta

**Fuentes de consulta**

- [Método `fetchColumn`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)
- [Guía sobre PDO y recomendación de A.Cedano](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)
- [Métodos de petición HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)
- [Método `errorInfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.errorinfo.php)

Recomiendo leas el último enlace, en PDO te ayudará a manejar la obtención (*si es que se da*) del posible error generado en el gestor de tu db.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ha funcionado de maravilla

Answer (score 1):

Te faltan un par de pasos para preparar correctamente esa consulta, entiendo que el fallo venga de ahí.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php

Modifica esta línea:

```
$query = "SELECT idUsuario, usuario, password, idSuscripcionFk FROM usuarios 
  WHERE usuario = '$user' AND password = '$pass' LIMIT 1;";
```

Así:

```
$query = "
    SELECT idUsuario 
      FROM usuarios 
      WHERE usuario = ? AND password = ?
      LIMIT 1;
";
```

Y ahora te falta, tras el método `prepare()`:

```
$resultado = $conn->prepare($query);
$resultado->bind_param('ss',$user,$pass);
$resultado->execute();
$resultado->bind_result($idUsuario);
if($resultado->fetch())
    echo 'Ingreso exitoso';
else echo 'Datos incorrectos';
```

Es un poco engorroso, pero mucho más seguro que un query normal.

### Ampliación de respuesta: de PDO a mysqli

Ahora que he visto que usas PDO, te propongo la opción más sencilla para que funcione la solución que te planteo: cambiar de PDO a mysqli modificando esta línea:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

A esta otra:

```
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_NAME,DB_PASS,DB_DATABASE);
```

Recuerda definir DB_DATABASE.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Pues no, tampoco me ha funcionado... Actualizaré la pregunta

Comment: David buena respuesta pero considera que el OP usa **PDO** y no mysqli por lo tanto el uso de métodos como `bind_param` no va

Comment: @BetaM tienes toda la razón. Modifico la respuesta. Si la montaña no va a Mahoma, ...

Answer (score 1):

El principal problema es que quieres realizar una consulta preparada pero hay varias inconsistencias en tu codigo:

1.- Tu consulta esta mal, para realizar una sentencia preparada, lo correcto seria realizar lo siguiente:

```
$query = "SELECT idUsuario, usuario, password, idSuscripcionFk FROM usuarios 
WHERE usuario = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1";
```

2.- Luego necesitas vincular los valores a tu consulta ejemplo:

```
$resultado = $conn->prepare($query);
$resultado->bind_param('ss',$user,$pass);
$resultado->execute();
```

3.- Haciendo lo anterior, podras obtener el resultado de tu consulta ejemplo:

```
$registro = $resultado->get_result();
```

4.- Ahora si estarias en condiciones de validar ejemplo:

```
if($registro->num_rows > 0){
      echo 'Ingreso exitoso.';
  }else{
      echo 'Datos incorrectos.';
  }
```

5.- Te dejo documentacion para que profundices mas en el tema:

[PHP Manul prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he hecho el típico copy/paste y no ha funcionado. SIgue sin mostrarme el echo con los datos incorrectos

Comment: Nikola, debemos tener en cuenta que la conexión del OP es con PDO y no mysqli, por lo que el método de bind_param aqui no aplica así como tampoco aplica el num_rows

Comment: Que tal @BetaM ! Cabe mencionar que el OP no había agregado esa información antes, de todos modos se agradece las observaciones. Saludos.